# Yesod Julius Interpolation of Messages

Tags: yesod, hamlet

I've been using Yesod's messages system to help keep my language consistent.  For example, I have a message named MsgBrand, which gets interpolated into Hamlet files with no problem.  However, I am now using a JavaScript library which needs this kind of information.

```
var tour = Tour.new();

tour.addSteps([
  { element: "#some-id",
    title:   "Some Title",
    content: "_{MsgTourStepFoo}"
  }
]);
```

However, `_{MsgTourStepFoo}` is appearing in the rendered JavaScript code verbatim.  In other words, there is no interpolation.  Is this normal or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal. We *could* have a i18n-variant of Julius, but have avoided it so far simply because it seems like it would be more confusion than it's worth. Instead, you can use [getMessageRender](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.4.2/20130922-179/yesod-core/Yesod-Core-Handler.html#v%3agetMessageRender) to get the message rendering function and then call it from Julius, something like:

```
Haskell:
messageRender <- getMessageRender

Julius:
content: "#{messageRender MsgTourStepFoo}"
```

Comment: Okay, I understand.  I find it kind of surprising though.  Thanks Michael, for Yesod and your help. :)

Comment: It's good, but I got this error: 
  Foundation.hs:85:26:
    No instance for (RenderMessage App message0)
      arising from a use of ‘getMessageRender’
    The type variable ‘message0’ is ambiguous